# Finding all indirectly connected nodes with specific relationship Gremlin

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, gremlin-server, janusgraph

Suppose I have the numerical ID of a Node in Gremlin.. utilized with

```
g.V(n_id)
```

Say this Node is a topic.

Each topic can have a question with relationship `threadOf`.

Each question can have an answer or comment with relationship `threadOf`

If I get a numerical ID as an input I'd like a gremlin query which returns all the questions related to this topic and all the answers or comments related to those questions

All relationships are `threadOf`

Is this possible with Gremlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this with Gremlin. Let's assume this graph (with Gremlin questions it is always helpful to include a small graph sample in the question itself like this):

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('topic').property('text','topic').as('t').
......1>   addV('question').property('text','question 1').as('q1').
......2>   addV('question').property('text','question 2').as('q2').
......3>   addV('comment').property('text','comment 1').as('c1').
......4>   addV('comment').property('text','comment 2').as('c2').
......5>   addV('answer').property('text','answer 1').as('a1').
......6>   addV('answer').property('text','answer 2').as('a2').
......7>   addE('threadOf').from('t').to('q1').
......8>   addE('threadOf').from('t').to('q2').
......9>   addE('threadOf').from('q1').to('c1').
.....10>   addE('threadOf').from('q1').to('c2').
.....11>   addE('threadOf').from('q1').to('a1').
.....12>   addE('threadOf').from('q2').to('a2').iterate()
```

The graph above is a tree so it might be best to return it as one. To do this we can use [tree step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#tree-step). The topic is at vertex id "0" so if we want all of the "threadOf" hierarchy we could just do:

```
gremlin> g.V(0L).out('threadOf').out('threadOf').tree().by('text')
==>[topic:[question 1:[comment 2:[],comment 1:[],answer 1:[]],question 2:[answer 2:[]]]]
```

That works, but it assumes we know the depth of the tree of "threadOf" edges (we step `out()` twice from vertex "0". If we don't know the depth we can do:

```
gremlin> g.V(0L).repeat(out('threadOf')).emit().tree().by('text')
==>[topic:[question 1:[comment 2:[],comment 1:[],answer 1:[]],question 2:[answer 2:[]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer.. the first solution partially works when I use `in` instead of `out`. As you said I don't know the depth of the tree so need to use the second solution. However when I use `in` for this I get an unexpected token error

Comment: `in` is a reserved word in groovy so you need to prefix it with the class name for that static import of the `in()` step. in other words, `g.V(0L).repeat(__.in('threadOf')).emit().tree().by('text')`

Comment: Amazing !! Thanks so much

Comment: Is there any reason this might work in gremlin terminal but not when executed in a script such as python?

Comment: yes see the first WARNING in the docs at this link: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-python - it again has to do with "in" being a reserved word. in python syntax "in" is referenced as "in_"